# Can I replace old capacitors that are leaking?

Tags: amplifier

I have an old audio amplifier with General Electric 2500 microfarad 100 volt DC storage capacitors that are leaking. I need to replace them. Will the audio quality change if I used 10,000 microfarad 100 volt DC capacitors?

Comment: A little more pulse current on the diodes will occur, depending on margin,ok

Answer (score 7):

If they are used in the power supply, then the only difference would be a small reduction in hum level due to the increased capacitance. If they are used to couple the AC signal to the speakers, then there could be a small difference in the low frequency response. In either case, it is unlikely that you notice any change in the overall audio quality. When you do the replacement, be sure to clean up any leaked fluid and be careful to wire them with the correct polarity.

Answer (score 0):

Such a dramatic change is unlikely to be without problems.

your 4 times larger capacitors will result in a higher crest factor in the rectifier, giving 4 times larger RMS current in the transformer (all else being equal)  this could cause it to overheat.

the higher peak currents before the capacitors will  cause more magnetic rectifier noise to be broadcast, you might hear this as a buzzing noise.

Comment: total transformer current will be the same as before, so I really dont see how it could be overheating.

Comment: @tobalt Ohmic losses are proportional to the *square* of the current. If the pulses charging the capacitor occupy 1/4 the time, they have 4x the current. That means 16x the peak loss, 4x the average loss, 4x the heat generated.